# Mobile browsers: update element on back button

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, css

I'm using JavaScript to display a CSS3 throbber when the user navigates on a mobile browser (specifically, when they use a swipe gesture to navigate pages). However, when the browser back button is used, the throbber persists in both iOS and Android. I've tried adding the following to the body onload, but it doesn't seem to be firing.

```
<body onload='document.getElementById("throbber").class="off";'>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to the Back/Forward Cache (bfcache) events: pageshow and/or pagehide. See https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Working_with_BFCache

Comment: That worked, thanks! For posterity, the code I used was:

    <body onpageshow='document.getElementById("throbber").class="off";'>

All that was needed is to replace onload with onpageshow.

Comment: @MikkelPaulson thank you for coming back and commenting on your answer. Too many people leave questions hanging with a "Great! Figured it out"